# PHPUnit for symfony2.1 - cannot redeclare xyz()

Tags: php, symfony, pear, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I read that PHPUnit can be installed with pear or with composer.
Because I'm on a windows with WAMPSERVER and a cygwin for console stuff and there is no pear installed, I installed PHPUnit via composer. And especially since symfony2.1 you must use composer, so [I choose this method](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html#installation.composer).

I add this into my composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
},
```

And then do a

```
php composer.phar install --dev
```

**//Update1 (thanks to theunraveler)**

The bin files (phpunit and phpunit.bat) are copied or linked to the bin directory of the app. But when I call `bin/phpunit -c app/` 
I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare assetic_init() (previously declared in C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\functions.php:20) in C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\functions.php on line 26

Call Stack:
    0.0005     128056   1. {main}() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:0
    0.0095     433520   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:42
    0.0096     436736   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:130
    0.0096     436952   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:139
    0.0144     683168   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:615
    0.0148     689328   6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:787
    0.0152     689448   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php:77
    0.0200    1013688   8. include_once('C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\app\bootstrap.php.cache') C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php:93
    0.0202    1016424   9. require_once('C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\app\autoload.php') C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\app\bootstrap.php.cache:3
    0.0204    1017424  10. require('C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\autoload.php') C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\app\autoload.php:5
    0.0205    1017440  11. ComposerAutoloaderInit::getLoader() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\autoload.php:7

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare assetic_init() (previously declared in C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\functions.php:20) in C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\kriswallsmith\assetic\src\functions.php on line 26
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:42
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:130
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:139
PHP   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:615
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:787
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php:77
PHP   8. include_once() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Fileloader.php:93
PHP   9. require_once() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\app\bootstrap.php.cache:3
PHP  10. require() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\app\autoload.php:5
PHP  11. ComposerAutoloaderInit::getLoader() C:\wamp_\www\symfony2.1\vendor\autoload.php:7
```

Why this will be executed, I don't define to search for tests in this directory.
I try to remove the file where the error occurs, but then I get a similar error: `cannot redeclare` error for another class/function. So it looks like the source is been loaded twice.

**//Update2** 
The phpunit.xml.dist was generated when I install symfony, I didn'T modify it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    syntaxCheck                 = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "bootstrap.php.cache" >

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!--
    <php>
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    </php>
    -->

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

</phpunit>
```

The errors still there when I delete the testsuites and filter block.

Comment: Can you show use the PHPunit config file (`phpunit.xml.dist`)? Maybe there is something wrong in it, or Composer created its own file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this, and a symlink was created in my project's `bin` directory. So I was able to run PHPUnit with `bin/phpunit`.

Comment: oh, I don't see it. phpunit works, but I get two errors from a vendors functinon.php (I edit my question)

Comment: Since symfony 2.1.2 the bin directory isn't in app/bin anymore. Now it's in vendor/bin and it works without problems now.

Comment: For me, phpunit was symlinked into the {project_root}/bin directory as well.